# Wpdb empty result only if language is Russian

Tags: query, wpdb, plugin-wpml

I'm having a little problem with `wpdb query`.
I need to change content of an HTML `select` by changing another one ( simple and clean ), so, this is my query:

```
$_queryString="SELECT stato_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE." AS stato FROM hn_references WHERE LOWER(continente_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE.")='".$_cont."' GROUP BY stato_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
$_queryResult=$wpdb->get_results($_queryString);
```

And it works, except on Russian. DB Charset is `utf8_generic_ci` and `HTML charset` is `utf8` too. I've tried put all results on arrays and check for string comparison, but that didn't work too, `get_results` still returning an empty array.

The strange thing is that I've copied-pasted that query into `phpMyAdmin`, and it works. I read about some encoding problems, and that `UTF-8` should solve this problem.

So, I've put this in my header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Those are in my `wp-config`:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

And db tables are stored as `utf8_general_ci`.

I've also tried this:

```
$_cont=mb_convert_encoding($_cont,'UTF-8');
$_queryString="SELECT stato_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE." AS stato FROM hn_references WHERE LOWER(continente_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE.")='".$_cont."' GROUP BY stato_".ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
```

But it's still not working.

Comment: if it return an empty array then there is 90% probability that there are simply no matching results

Comment: No, there are. I can see them on `phpMyAdmin` by pasting the same query

Comment: what query did you use in phpmyadmin, was it exactly the same one you get after setting the variable (i.e. did you print it and just C&P it or tried to recreate what you think it should be?

Comment: Copied-pasted `$_queryString`

Comment: and you used the same user wordpress uses?

Comment: Yes I did. It's the same user, the same uses, the same HTML selects and the same query. Only language changes, as you can see. I've added other things to my question, please check them out

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
As I was boiling my head to find another approach, I've seen that `stato_ru` column was the only one not having `utf8_generic_ci` encoding...